# How to declare array that correspond to bit size of the int in c?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, declaration

Basically i need something like this:

```cpp
#if (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) == 32
INT_MASKS[32] = {
    0x00000001, 0x00000003, 0x00000007, 0x0000000F,
    0x0000001F, 0x0000003F, 0x0000007F, 0x000000FF,
    ...
};
#elif (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT) == 64
INT_MASKS[64] = {
    0x0000000100000001, 0x0000000300000003, 0x0000000700000007, 0x0000000F0000000F,
    0x0000001F0000001F, 0x0000003F0000003F, 0x0000007F0000007F, 0x000000FF000000FF,
    ...
};
#else
    #error unsupported architecture
#endif;
```

There's more than only one array in each #if #else branch, so working equivalent would save me a lot of space. Also, some arrays contain loads of expressions, which i would like to evaluate during compilation. Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc *et al* define `__INT_MAX__` - you could use this for gcc and gcc-compatible compilers and then maybe define it explicitly for any other compilers that you need to support:

```
#if __INT_MAX__ == 0x7fffffff
INT_MASKS[32] = {
    0x00000001, 0x00000003, 0x00000007, 0x0000000F,
    0x0000001F, 0x0000003F, 0x0000007F, 0x000000FF,
    ...
};
#elif __INT_MAX__ == 0x7fffffffffffffff
INT_MASKS[64] = {
    0x0000000100000001, 0x0000000300000003, 0x0000000700000007, 0x0000000F0000000F,
    0x0000001F0000001F, 0x0000003F0000003F, 0x0000007F0000007F, 0x000000FF000000FF,
    ...
};
#else
    #error unsupported architecture
#endif
```

Comment: I'd go one further: `INT_MAX == INT32_MAX` is semantically more obvious. :)

Comment: Perhaps, but `__INT_MAX__` is already defined by the compiler, whereas  `INT_MAX` and `INT32_MAX` require specific headers (`limits.h` and `stdint.h`)

Comment: Which are standard C99 headers... ;)

Comment: Maybe question that should not be in this thread, but still: How is this `__INT_MAX__` calculated, or is it set statically in the compiler ? I'm just curious :)

Comment: @Jonathan: unfortunately certain well known compilers *still* do not support C99. ;-)

Comment: @Neko: compilers typically pre-define certain useful macros - e.g. type `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null` to see all the macros that are pre-defined for gcc

Comment: I did a lil examination of GCC and found that all data type size macros are indirectly set by user (`-arch` switch). Why doesn't gcc compute these bit sizes ? Wouldn't it be better, more user friendly ? Sorry for bothering u that much.

Comment: @Neko: Compute them how? `int` isn't defined by the hardware--it's a type defined at the C level and upward, so it's the compiler's responsibility to determine its representation in memory, its size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead?:

```
#include <limits.h>

#if UINT_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFF
INT_MASKS[32] = {
    0x00000001, 0x00000003, 0x00000007, 0x0000000F,
    0x0000001F, 0x0000003F, 0x0000007F, 0x000000FF,
    ...
};
#elif UINT_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
INT_MASKS[64] = {
    0x0000000100000001, 0x0000000300000003, 0x0000000700000007, 0x0000000F0000000F,
    0x0000001F0000001F, 0x0000003F0000003F, 0x0000007F0000007F, 0x000000FF000000FF,
    ...
};
#else
#error unsupported architecture
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The way this is usually done is to write a separate program that generates the declarations so as to avoid the tedium of typing out all those constant-expressions.  For example the INT_MASKS declaration could be generated by this code excerpt:

```
int i, intbits = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;
if (intbits == 32) {
    printf("unsigned INT_MASKS[%d] = {\n", intbits);
    for (i = 0; i < intbits; i++) {
        unsigned mask = (unsigned)(~0) >> (intbits - i - 1);
        printf("    0x%08x,\n", mask, mask);
    }
    printf("};\n", intbits);
} else if (intbits == 64) {
    int half = intbits / 2;
    printf("unsigned INT_MASKS[%d] = {\n", intbits);
    for (i = 0; i < intbits; i++) {
        unsigned mask = (unsigned)(~0) >> (half - (i%half) - 1);
        printf("    0x%08x%08x,\n", mask, mask);
    }
    printf("};\n", intbits);
}
```